# How do I create a pip installable project?

Tags: python, pip

How do I create a pip installable project? How do you register with pip?

What meta data config should all projects have in order to allow integration and easy import.

Comment: You can reach all the information you need from the [**PyPI homepage**](http://pypi.python.org/pypi).

Comment: Inspired by @wjoba I wrote a guide here https://gist.github.com/stevepeak/5520777 enjoy!

Comment: I'm maintaining a python project template that's ready to be installed with pip, here: https://github.com/DarkTrick/python_project_template

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to

1. Write a setup.py file
2. Run python setup.py sdist tar gzipped file.
3. Run register or submit the project using the web form.

You can register using:

```
>> python setup.py register
```

An exmaple setup.py file is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from distutils.core import setup

 setup(name='Distutils',
  version='1.0',
  description='Python Distribution Utilities',
  author='Greg Ward',
  author_email='gward@python.net',
  url='http://www.python.org/sigs/distutils-sig/',
  packages=['distutils', 'distutils.command'],
 )
```

Users will then just have to upack the taz file and run install..

```
>> python setup.py install
```

Comment: Here is the current example setup.py file as per PYPA: https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject/blob/master/setup.py

Answer (score 11):

Or, if you're feeling fancy (read: *lazy*)...

1. `sudo easy_install PasteScript`
2. `paster create mynewpackage`
3. answer the questions!
4. `cd mynewpackage`
5. `python setup.py sdist`
6. `python setup.py register`
7. answer the questions!

Seems like more steps, but the [PasteScript](http://pythonpaste.org/script/) package handles a lot of the dirty work. Do yourself a favor and install it, use it, and never look back ;)

Comment: There is also [this](http://guide.python-distribute.org/creation.html) excellent tutorial if you're looking for a more thorough explanation of how to create and distribute a python package.

Comment: You can also install via pip: `sudo pip install PasteScript`

Comment: That tutorial link is dead.

Answer (score 1):

I wish `PasteScript` did the job because it seems straightforward but it simply didn't work for me. I got my code uploaded to the `pip` repository with Peter Down's [quick but well-explained tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20180421041403/http://peterdowns.com:80/posts/first-time-with-pypi.html).

Also, remember that if you are trying to have your code `import` from the package, you have to put it in `__init__.py`, which is sufficient for most projects.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out libmaker. It makes it easy to make packages. [This](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/libmaker) is the link to the homepage and documentation.